# Показ превьюшной картинки без сохранения на сервере

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, gd, formdata

Пытаюсь уменьшить превьюшную еще не загруженную на сервер картинку в размерах на стороне сервера. Для этой задачи использую библиотеку GD, а также Ajax.

Отправляю Ajax запрос. Всё проходит без проблем, но теперь у меня задача показать картинку пользователю. Как это реализовать?

Схема такого типа:

1). *index.html* отправляет Ajax запрос, и здесь же нужно ее отобразить.

2). *image.php* - сам обработчик, где идет уменьшение размера картинки.

В самом обработчике сохранить, ресайзнуть картинку и манипулировать ее как угодно не составляет труда. А вот вытащить её не выходит.

Код такой (не полный):

**(index.html)**

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function()
{
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', $('#id_input_file')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'image.php',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('.appendThis').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**(image.php)**

```
$filename = $_POST['image'];
// дальше сам процесс ресайза.. Думаю, нет смысла его вставлять
```

Comment: Что значит `А вот вытащить её не выходит.`? Что возвращает скрипт `Image.php`?

Comment: Скрипт `image.php` возвращает саму картинку, если отправлять запрос с перезагрузкой страницы.

Comment: `Вытащить не выходит`

не понимаю каким образом это реализовать

Comment: @u_mulder если вытащить картинку подобным способом `<img src="image.php">` то он выведет картинку которое было сформировано на php статично. Но в моем случаи немного по другому, т.к. картинка формируется динамично, через `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` поэтому не получается реализовать.

Как реализовать задуманное?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ваш скрипт .php на сервере должен обработать картинку, положить её в нужное место на сервере и просто вернуть ссылку на неё. А дальше вы при успешном ответе от сервера меняете атрибут `src` у картинки на клиенте и показываете её. Правильно делать так:

1. Скрипт на сервере должен отвечать HTTP кодом `200` в случае успеха и
   `400` или `500` в случае ошибки
2. Возвращать лучше в JSON. Формируйте массив

```php
if (!$error){
    $file = ['image' => '/avatars/user_1231212.png'];

    // Я не знаю, как вы выводите ответ, так что просто
    // делаю echo, но вы делайте как вам надо
    echo json_encode($file);
} else {
    // В случае ошибки выводить её
    echo json_encode(['error' => $error]);
}
```

3. Создайте пустую картинку на странице, куда будете подгружать готовое изображение, а также область, где выводить ошибку:

```html
<img scr="" width="125" height="125" id="userAvatar"/>
<div id="error" style="display: none;"></div>
```

4. Ну и после ответа сервера либо выводить картинку, либо выводить ошибку:

```js
$.post('/image.php', formData, null, 'json')
    .done( function(data, status) {
        if (data.image !== undefined){
            $('#userAvatar').attr('src', data.image);
        } else {
            $('#error').text('Некорректный ответ сервера').show();
        }
    })
    .fail( function(data, status) {
        if (data.error !== undefined){
            $('#error').text('Ошибка при обработке изображения: ', data.error).show();
        } else {
            $('#error').text('Неизвестная ошибка сервера, код: ' + status).show();
        }
    })
);
```

И ещё. Не используйте относительные пути вроде `index.php`, используйте абсолютные `/index.php`! Иначе потом можете поиметь проблем с отлавливанием ошибок.

**Если вам надо локально обрабатывать изображение, вот разжёванные ответы, правда на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded**

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. `положить её в нужное место на сервере и просто вернуть ссылку на неё` в этом все и дело, мне не нужно картинку загружать на сервер. Возможно ли как-то без загрузки картинки на сервер реализовать задуманное?

Comment: По опыту, надо показывать *результат*, а не исходник. Если вы и так загружаете её на сервер, ну так и покажите именно тут готовую картинку. Иначе в чём смысл? Экономить траффик?

Comment: А без пере сохранения никак нельзя?

Comment: @PoyCc Добавил в ответ ссылку на вопрос о локальной обработке изображений

Comment: У меня похожее решение есть. В данном решении есть один минус, качество картинки не получится JavaScript'ом изменить, на более худшее, без использования canvas'а. А на canvas'е решать проблему я не хочу. Единственный вариант, который у меня остался, это использовать серверную часть, но без дополнительной загрузки картинки на сам сервер. Парадокс, я понимаю, но именно такой механизм мне и нужен.

Comment: @PoyCc Пардон, но это невозможно. Не будете же вы у каждого клиента запускать локальный сервер =) Либо вы загружаете картинку на сервер, обрабатываете её там и возвращаете результат, либо обрабатываете локально и загружаете на сервер обработанную. Для этого можно использовать готовые решения вроде [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/) . Во втором случае вам всё-равно будет необходимо на сервере проверить все параметры изображения.

Answer (score 0):

Вы и так загружаете картинку на сервер через Ajax и она находится на сервере.
Используйте pluploader, он может обрезать и отобразить.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: На опыте. Расставляя все по полочкам - человек нечему не научится.

Comment: Как мне кажется, все наоборот. Более того, Stack Overflow предназначен именно для обмена знаниями.

Comment: Я хочу максимально минимизировать свой сайт. Загрузка дополнительных плагинов для решения узконаправленных задач, на мой взгляд не айс. Каждый раз подключать плагины... ну кому как. Мне хочется без этого обойтись.